# How to obtain the file paths of nth level subdirectory entries in Python?

Tags: python, path, directory, subdirectory, os.path

I am trying to get the file paths of all files in nth subdirectory of a particular directory (in Python) as shown below:

```
Directory
   |
   |+ Subdirectory_1
   |       |
   |       |+ Subdirectory_11
   |       |       |
   |       |       |+ ...............       
   |       |       
   |       |                     
   |       |+ Subdirectory_12
   |       |       |
   |       |       |+ ...............       
   |       |       
   |       |+ Subdirectory_13
   |       |       |
   |       |       |+ ...............  
   |       |       
   |       |+ .......................
   |
   |+ Subdirectory_2
   |       |
   |       |+ Subdirectory_21
   |       |       |
   |       |       |+ ...............       
   |       |       
   |       |                     
   |       |+ Subdirectory_22
   |       |       |
   |       |       |+ ...............       
   |       |       
   |       |+ Subdirectory_23
   |       |       |
   |       |       |+ ...............  
   |       |       
   |       |+ .......................
   |
   | ...............................
```

The list has to give me full file paths of all the files in all the subdirectories. I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
import os
directory_path = os.path.abspath('Directory')
list_folder = [folder for folder in sorted(os.listdir(directory_path)) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory_path, folder))]
list_file = [file for file in sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(directory_path, list_folder)))]
```

Moreover this would give me files only in the 2nd level, I need it for n levels of subdirectories. And is there way to split the path based on levels, e.g. if the entire path is:

```
/home/Directory/Subdirectory_1/Subdirectory_11/Sub_directory_111 .../Subdirectory_n
```

I need to get individual folder names based on the level like:

```
folder_name(2): Subdirectory_1
folder_name(3): Subdirectory_11
folder_name(3): Sub_directory_111
     :                :
folder_name(n): Subdirectory_n
```

Comment: You're looking for os.walk() : https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: I tried using os.walk() but it creates a generator, how do I access this generator?

Comment: @nxcr you can list it, loop it, ... see [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: It gives me only the first level, how do I go up to the nth level?